# When I save file, why Visual Studio Code does format my file?

Tags: view, formatting, save, visual-studio-code, save-as

Good Day!

Help me, please.

[This is My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A61OW.jpg). When I click CTRL+S, or click "Save All", or "Save", My Visual Studio Code format my all documents like ALT+SHIFT+F... But, I didnt click this fuction. [And my CSS, or HTML code after Click button "Save"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWJ2e.jpg). How can you see, my big code Looks terrible. How to remove this function?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue and that problem is caused by the extension "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter".I uninstalled it and then it works! Hope it helps someone!

Comment: Oh thank you so much for this! i have been looking for a solution for so long!

Comment: I can confirm that it was the case for me too. Note that I had to restart VS Code after removing the extension.

Comment: I have same problem. Is it possible to use this extension but somehow disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 4):

Go to setting (Ctrl + ,) and change editor.formatOnSave from true to false: `"editor.formatOnSave": false,`

Comment: I had/have "false". And I even reinstalled the program, all the same situation. Maybe, do you have another advice?

Answer (score 2):

just make sure you **disable/untick/make it false***(however your setting appears)* in **FormatOnSave** both in the **user** and **workspace** in *VS CODE SETTINGS*

Answer (score 1):

I just [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoNTX.png)had this issue as well and had to go to the tab >>> Code/Preferences/Settings/
In the search bar type in Formatting. Then look for what is being formatted on save. Mine was the "HTML > Format: Enable" I unchecked it and it fixed my problem. I know this is an old issue but I hope this answer helps others now in 2019.

Comment: I missed the part of filling in the image description :)